# Can only adopt one child?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I went to adopt Frodnar and Dorthe, but at my house only Dorthe was there, and I can no longer adopt any other child (Frodnar is still at the orphanage) It says both child beds are owned, no matter what house I move too, I've tried my own in The Pale, and Breezehome in Whiterun, they both have child bedrooms, with child chests for both kids, why can't I adopt my second child? I can no longer talk to stray children, or the people at the orphanage, and I cant go back to a previous save, because realizing I had to wait a few days for my children to end up at my house, I went off and did a lot of quests, I did 3 Daedric quests finishing the Oblivion walker achievement, and a ton of over misc. quests.
(Im on Xbox)

Answer (score 3):

Ok.
In Breezehome, there are 2 beds. Your master bed, and a followers bed.

In most other houses, the same thing applies so make sure you have 2 non-owned beds not including the master bed for your children.

Second, if you own the DLC houses, you may want to build a bedroom addon as well as the main halls 3 beds. Because you can obtain a Bard, a Housecarl and a Steward, thats 3 beds taken already. It's basically all based off of **free** beds.

And 2 children is the limit as-well.

Also, you said you have 2 beds taken up and only one child. Its because your housecarl owns one and Dorthe most likely owns the other.

Comment: And your saying both beds are owned. One is your housecarl and the other is most likely Dorthe.

Comment: You should edit your answer instead of commenting on it.

Comment: Woops, I didnt notice. Was meant to comment on the question. Might as well add it into the answer anyway.

Comment: I own every possible bed in my house with the addon bedroom wing. I killed everyone living in my house besides my kid and wife, and the  CHILDREN beds in the bedroom wings are owned, they both have CHESTS, the 3 beds upstairs are not owned, but still slept in by my housecarl, my bard and steward seem to never sleep. In total I have 6 beds in my house and 5 people, I decided to move my family to breezeholm to see if it was a problem with the house. As soon as I completely furnished the house, the Children's bedroom beds were set as owned. I said I had childrens bedrooms and chests.

Comment: Make a backup of your game. Go find another random kid to adopt. If it works, Frodnar is glitched. If not, your game is glitched. Skyrim can be very glitchy at times... Also, did you actually 'adopt' Frodnar and then he wont come home? Or it just wont show the dialog?